# Besides, Other than, But, Except, Except for

Tags: synonyms

> Is there something that is not the apple on the table?
>   Is there something but the apple on the table?

Are they the same in meaning?

> I can eat everything but tomatoes.
>   I can eat everything that is not tomatoes.

I know they are the same. But I think it’s because of “everything”. “Something” means a thing.

I want to know what to use instead of “but”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both **everything** and **something**. Something isn’t a specific object it is just an object.

Your second example sounds much more common than the first example regarding the apple.

If you use the first apple sentence you need a comma as it has a subordinate clause:

> Is there something, but the apple, on the table?

For the tomatoes sentence the first sentence is much more common than the second sentence.

Instead of but try using except:

> I can eat everything **except** tomatoes

Or apart from:

> I can eat everything **apart from** tomatoes

Or not including:

> I can eat everything **not including** tomatoes

Comment: Thank you. Can I use “Besides, Other than, Except for” as well?

Comment: @Yamacure Yes you can, if I helped please upvote my answer (the up arrow), it would be higher appreciated

Comment: Thank you very much